# (callable not found or import error) no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi

This has been bothering me for hours and have no idea what is going on.  When I tried visiting the site through only ip.  I get the word `internal server error`

I get this error log when I restart `daemon and uwsgi`

```
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Set PythonHome to /root/wxr/wxr
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0xe0db20
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 437520 bytes (427 KB) for 5 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/wxr/wxr/main/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

I do not have virtual environment setup so everything is installed in `ubuntu 16.04` directly using `root` user to setup instead of having additional user

I have this as my server block in `site-available`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location /media  {
                alias /root/wxr/wxr/mediafiles;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        }



        location /static/ {
                alias /root/wxr/wxr/static;
        }

        location / {
            include /root/wxr/wxr/uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi/wxr.sock;
            uwsgi_param Host $host;
            uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;

        }
}
```

my `/etc/uwsgi/sites/wxr.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
project = wxr
base =/root


#chdir = %(base)/%(project)/%(project)
#home = %(base)/%(project)/%(project)
wsgi-file = /root/wxr/wxr/main/wsgi.py
chdir = /root/wxr/wxr
home = /root/wxr/wxr

module = main.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /tmp/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
enable-threads = true
no-site = true

req-logger = file:/tmp/reqlog
logger = file:/tmp/errlog
```

my `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/uwsgi; chown root:www-data /tmp/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What version of Django are you running? And is there any reason not to upgrade to Python 3?

Comment: @Gnoliz django 1.9, as for not upgrading is because all the changes need to be done after upgraded which does not have time at the moment to make all the changes and tests

Comment: did you use virtualenv or pyenv?

Comment: @seuling nope.  I just figured it will work if I use with `virtualenv`, that's why my `home = /root/wxr/wxr` is the same as `chdir` but why is that though?  For before, it used to work without havinvg `virtualenv` so I didn't think this is the problem before until I really had no other thoughts on what is going on

Comment: Then it mean your error occurs because of python path. It can be work without virtualenv, but it can't be without serving accurate python path.

Comment: @seuling um..I get what you mean. so if I am not using `virtualenv` in my config should be `home=/usr/bin/python` ?